# In Redmine is it possible to give permissions to non admin users to add new values to custom fields?

Tags: redmine

We use custom fields in our trackers to have, for example, the list of customers so we can identify the customer requesting something.

Every time we have a new customer we need to add a new value to this custom field. 
Is it possible to give permissions to a normal user so he can do this by himself or does he need to be an admin as this feature is under the Administration menu?

Comment: No, Normal user make it as admin

Comment: Put it as an answer and I will accept it. Looks like the permissions matrix could be improved a bit, to be an admin to modify a list of elements does not seem the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible because normal users don't have access to administrator options. A possible solution is when you create new normal users make them with admin role.

Comment: It is not an option for me. I don't want anyone to change a tracker or something else other than the enumerated fields.

Comment: yes all options coming under administrator menu only